# What is the distance from the Earth where the centripetal force would equal the gravitational force?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, centripetal-force

I've been trying to find the length of an unbendable and unbreakable tether of zero mass extending off the surface of the Earth with a mass at its end, where the centripetal force would equal the gravitational force.  However I am getting a number that seems to be way too high.

Constants:

  Period of the Earth
  $(T_e)$
  is
  $86400$
  s
  Radius of the Earth
  $(r_e)$
  is
  $6371000$
  m
  Mass of Earth
  $(m_e)$
  is
  $5.97 \times 10^{24}$
  kg
  Gravitational Constant
  $(G)$
  is
  $6.67 \times 10^{-11}$
  N·kg⁻²·m²

Centripetal acceleration:

  $F = {m_o v^2 \over r}$
  *(1)*

Gravity between object $(m_o)$ and the Earth $(m_e)$:

  $F = {G m_o m_e \over r^2}$
  *(2)*

Geosynchronous orbit speed:

  $v = {2 \pi r \over T_e}$
  *(3)*

My calculations:

  ${m_o v^2 \over r} = {G m_o m_e \over{r^2}}$
  *Combine 1 & 2*
  ${v^2 \over r} = {G m_e \over r^2}$
  *Cancel out $m_o$*
  $r = {G m_e \over v^2}$
  *Isolate r (4)*
  $r = {G m_e \over ({2 π r \over T_e})^2}$
  *Combine 3 & 4*
  $r = {G m_e T_e^2 \over {4 π² r^2}}$
  *Simplify*
  $r^3 = {G m_e T_e^2 \over {4 π^2}}$
  *Isolate $r$*
  $r = \sqrt[\leftroot{-1}\uproot{2}\scriptstyle 3]{G m_e T_e^2 \over {4 π^2}}$

Given this equation, the value for $r$ is ${7.54}\times{10^{22}}$, but I thought that the value was much smaller than the distance to the moon, which is a mean of $384,000,000$ m.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have made an error whilst using your calculator and failed to take the cube root?

Comment: Yeah @Farcher, forgot to take the cubed root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your algebra is fine. I put a slightly modified version of your equation into the Google calculator, using the [gravitational parameter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_gravitational_parameter) of Earth and got 42241.0957 km.

Here's the "search" string I used:

```
((3.986004418E14m^3*86400^2/(2pi)^2)^(1/3)
```

To get the correct geosynchronous radius of 42164km, we need to use the sidereal period of rotation, not the mean solar day.

```
((3.986004418E14m^3*86164.0905^2/(2pi)^2)^(1/3)
```

yields 42164.1696 km.

My guess is that you accidentally forgot to take the cube root, and also got some wrong powers of 10 from mistaking grams for kilograms &/or metres for kilometres.

Comment: Yeah, seems that I forgot to take the cubed root. Doh!  Oh, and thanks for the sidereal day.  Didn't even think about that.

Answer (score 1):

I think any object in  a circular orbit would have reached that equilibrium.  Also you might be interested in space elevators.?
https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=dc8_AuzeYKE

Answer (score 0):

You can check the calculation [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5B(6.67*10%5E(-11)*5.97*10%5E(24)*86400%5E2)%2F(4*pi%5E2)%5D%5E(1%2F3)). I got $\approx 10^7$, which is near $\frac{r_{moon}}{{100}}$